# Build only specific module of angular application

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-builder, angularbuild

I am working on an a large scale angular application which has more than 500 pages. It has a lot of modules which are lazily loaded. Now the problem is that our app takes too much time to build because of its size, so whenever we have to publish even little change in any module we have to build the whole and publish it which is time taking process. So i am looking for a way, somehow to build only those modules which and changed and publish them instead of building and publishing whole app. I wanted to ask if this is possible? and if yes how?

Comment: i with my teammates have same problem. our prob build on very good pc build about 15m. if launch build from teamcity on our some server - preprod build (like prod but with sourcemaps) take about 30m for some little fixes

Comment: @НикитаСереда its the same issue with our team as well, which is super irritating and time taking most of the times